# How to programmatically fetch ruby documentation of corelib / stdlib?

Tags: ruby

I have a big array. This array has all of ruby stdlib in like this format:

```
Array#size
Array#push
String#replace
String#<<
```

And so on. Now I wish to find the corresponding documentation of that method
and give it back to the user. (It is like a cheap REPL, a mini irb if you
so will - and I only need this mini functionality, nothing fully fledged.)

How could I find the part where Array#push is documented?
I am fine using rdoc/yard/ri, I only need to get the 
docu from there in a string-form.

Comment: What about just opening a window with the docs at `ruby-doc.org`?  Just change your array to a hash with the URL the value; e.g., `Enumerable#count => http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-#{RUBY_VERSION}/Enumerable.html#method-i-count`.  On my computer, `RUBY_VERSION => "2.1.1"`, so that URL would be `http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-count`. As these URLs have a consistent structure, you could generate most from the class or module and method name, but use of a hash may be easiest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dig down into the RDoc documentation and access the [Rdoc::RI::Driver](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/rdoc/rdoc/RDoc/RI/Driver.html) code that `ri` uses, then play some games with how it outputs the data to capture what would normally go to the screen by using a [StringIO](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) object:

```
require 'rdoc'
require 'stringio'

ri = RDoc::RI::Driver.new(RDoc::RI::Driver.process_args(%w[-T --format=ansi ]))
ri.use_stdout = true

ri_output = ''
$stdout = StringIO.new(ri_output)
ri.display_method('Array#push') 
$stdout = STDOUT

puts ri_output
```

Which results in:

```
[0m[1;32mArray#push[m

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ary.push(obj, ... )   -> ary

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Append --- Pushes the given object(s) on to the end of this array. This
expression returns the array itself, so several appends may be chained
together. See also Array#pop for the opposite effect.

  a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
  a.push("d", "e", "f")
          #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
  [1, 2, 3,].push(4).push(5)
          #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Change the output type to `markdown` to get output that doesn't use the ANSI terminal display codes:

```
ri = RDoc::RI::Driver.new(RDoc::RI::Driver.process_args(%w[-T --format=markdown ]))
```

Which results in:

```
# Array#push

(from ruby core)
---
    ary.push(obj, ... )   -> ary

---

Append --- Pushes the given object(s) on to the end of this array. This
expression returns the array itself, so several appends may be chained
together. See also Array#pop for the opposite effect.

    a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
    a.push("d", "e", "f")
            #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
    [1, 2, 3,].push(4).push(5)
            #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This little piece of magic allows us to capture the normal output that would go to STDOUT on the console into a string:

```
ri_output = ''
$stdout = StringIO.new(ri_output)
```

At that point, all normal `STDOUT`-based output will be stored in `ri_output` and not go to the console. Following that it's important to reassign `STDOUT` back to `$stdout` so `puts` output goes to the console again:

```
$stdout = STDOUT
```

It's probably possible to intercept the output prior to it going to the normal `ri` console output, but I didn't see a method, or way, for doing that that stood out.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `ri` with a system call. For example

```
`ri Array#push`
```

returns

```
= Array#push

(from ruby core)
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ary.push(obj, ... )   -> ary

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Append --- Pushes the given object(s) on to the end of this array. This
expression returns the array itself, so several appends may be chained
together. See also Array#pop for the opposite effect.

  a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
  a.push("d", "e", "f")
          #=> ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
  [1, 2, 3,].push(4).push(5)
          #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Hi. I upvoted your answer. I don't like to have to depend on an external command though - for instance, a system might not have "ri" installed and available, and then it would not work. Perhaps someone has an idea how ri solves this problem?